# Add a link to a local file to email using mailto Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email, outlook

I need to pass data from one html form to another through email. I'm having some issues inserting a link to a local file. Once the outlook client opens, the link is not formatted correctly and is not a hyperlink. This is my send() function from my form

```
function send() 
{
    var name = document.getElementById('Fname').value;
    var company = document.getElementById('company').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var str = "Link to IT Web Report"
    var linkToReport = str.link('S:\IT\Applications\Aleds Work\Guest WIFI access\ITTaskWebReport.html?name='+name+'&company='+company+'&email='+email);
    var link = 'mailto:FHCNetAlert@fhc.co.uk?subject= Guest WIFI request'
             +'&body=A request for guest WIFI access was made. Details:- %0D%0A'
             +'%0D%0A Name: '+document.getElementById('Fname').value +
             '%0D%0A Company: '+document.getElementById('company').value +
             '%0D%0A Email: '+document.getElementById('email').value +
             '%0D%0A' +linkToReport;
    window.location.href = link;
}
```

This is how this link appears in Microsoft outlook -

```
<a href="S:ITApplicationsAleds WorkGuest WIFI accessITTaskWebReport.html?name=Aled Hughes
```

As you can see, its not the right format, its not a link, and its missing the company variable and also the email variable. Any help out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass URL's in `mailto` links you'll need to URLencode them, and you also want to escape your backslashes.  I don't have a windows machine to hand to test, but you want something like;

```
var linkToReport = str.link(encodeURIComponent('S:\\\\IT\Applications\\Aleds Work\\Guest WIFI access\\ITTaskWe...'))
```

That should hopefully set you on the right path ;)

You'll need to use `encodeURIComponent` as in [mailto URI's](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6068.txt), GET-like parameters are interpreted as email headers such as `body`, `cc`, so it will break on the components in your URI like `company`.

Also watch out for people with names like "O'Mally" i.e. add more logic to convert single quotes, as the [MDN page on encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) says;

> encodeURIComponent escapes all characters except the following:
>   alphabetic, decimal digits, - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )

Comment: Thanks for the help. Im now getting the backslashes in the URI but nothing after the first & symbol. any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, I think Ive cracked it. But now havina a issue with the hyperlink format.

Comment: Then you should probably Accept this answer and ask a new question ;)

Comment: yep all sorted now. Thanks again for the help!